# How to increase the default screen resolution without a monitor plugged in

Tags: 10.04, resolution, screen, monitor

i have kinda problem with setting my resolution on ubuntu 10.04

the thing is that i installed the machine and put it away without mouse, keyboard and monitor (i am currently remote with VNC viewer)

now the problem is that without a monitor plugged in i can`t increase the screen resolution above 800x600

how can i increase it let`s say to 1024x768

Comment: btw i found that xrandr offers just these:


" Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.0*    56.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   400x300        60.0     56.0  
   320x240        60.0 "

Comment: Can you select a resolution in your VNC client?

Comment: nope, tryed that was my first thought :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 - Add Fake Display when No Monitor is Plugged In](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/ubuntu-14-04-add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in)

Answer (score 1):

I found a page that might be just the thing for you.....

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Relevant section:

Adding undetected resolutions
Due to buggy hardware or drivers, your monitor's correct resolutions may not always be detected. For example, the EDID data block queried from your monitor may be incorrect.

If the mode already exists, but just isn't associated for the particular output, you can add it like this:

```
xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600
```

If the mode doesn't yet exist, you'll need to create it first by specifying a modeline:

```
xrandr --newmode <Mode``Line>
```

You may create a modeline using the gtf or cvt utility. For example, if you want to add a mode with resolution 800x600 at 60 Hz, you can enter the following command: (The output is shown following.)

```
cvt 800 600 60
# 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
```

Then copy the information after the word "Modeline" into the xrandr command:

```
xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync
```

After the mode is entered, it needs to be added to the output using the --addmode command as explained above.